# How to Query Django ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: django

Please I need help with getting the result of querying my ManyToMany fields.

Basically I have the following models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

How should I query my book model to show all the authors of each book, based on the book_id and without the book_id, and how to query all the books that were written by one author?

I have tried to follow the Docs where Pizza and Topping but I'm not getting it, so thanks in advance friends and have a good day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get all the authors given a book you just do:

```
my_book.authors.all()
```

The second query is much more complicated: you need to use annotations to get the count of authors for each book, and filter on those whose count is one:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Book.objects.annotate(author_count=Count('authors')).filter(author_count=1)
```

Comment: Mr: Daniel , i need your help again , now i am able to query Authors name by useing  :  book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=id)
    authors = book.authors.all() , but the problem is that iam getting the result in the following format :   Written By : [<Author: dody back>, <Author: Bosten Ollen>], so how can i render authors names without the model and list and <> tages .and another problem i am facing is how can i render the authors of of each book without passing the book_id to the function " def books_list(request): ", in case of showing all  books in the index page . thanking you so much .

Comment: Firstly you should accept the answer to this question; then you should ask your follow-ups as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

For getting all the authors of a book using `ManyToManyField` you should use `related_name` attribute of your `Book. authors` field. ex: `authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name="Books")`.

And then the query is `my_author.books.all()` which is syntactic sugar of `my_author.book_set.all()`